# I want to populate my tableview from my NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, json, uitableview

```
- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
    self.office = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    self.files = [office objectForKey:@"files"];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.files.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *file = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [file objectAtIndex:1];  //here i want to get data from the array
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    return cell;
    NSLog(@"files:\n%@", file);
}
```

I have a json response that i have stored in NSDictionary offices, and array in that json is stored in NSArray files,now i have given files array to another NSDictionary file and according to data that stored in that file i want that data in my table row, but i don't have any "key" in my files array only value in that array,

so my question is that how can i point that value in that my file dictionary, i have make comment where i want that please see that comment....

Comment: Why aren't you using `[file objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` ?

Comment: [file objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     //does not work

Comment: [files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   //is worked

Comment: How can you have a dictionary without keys?

Comment: log the file and checkout what you want to display and use accordingly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *file = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`NSDictionary` is indexed with keys, so you'll have to obtain the string with `objectForKey:`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [file objectForKey:@"fileName"];
```

Comment: This dont work for me,see i said that my array only contain value does not contain any key so [file objectForKey:@"fileName"] does not work.

Comment: You might want to post the output of `file` then, it's hard for anyone to help when we do not know the structure of your data

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: this what i give to that cell does that make any difference because its solved my problem

Comment: Well it obviously makes a difference if it solves your problem. You might want to read up on the differences between an NSArray and NSDictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must either misunderstand how an NSDictionary works or else the objects that you're accessing in self.files are not actually NSDictionaries. If they are in fact NSDictionary objects they need to be accessed like runmad says with

```
[file objectForKey:@"keyName"]
```

If there are no keys then you are dealing with a different type of object and we would need to know more specifics to be able to help you. As you posted the question runmad has given you the correct answer.

Comment: self.files is not NSDictionary its an array,I have give that array into NSDictionary file,but now i have droped that idea and give array to cell like this

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parser NSJSONSerialization may not be creating the NSDictionary/NSArray structures you think you have. You'll have to check your JSON, e.g. with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com), then use NSLog to have a look at what is placed in your dictionaries/arrays. Also try some of the NSJSONReadingOptions options.